# How to run different Django projects under different Domains on one web server?

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, http

I am trying to running two different projects in my web server. I want them to be pointed by different domain. So I configured my httpd.conf like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin me@web1.com
    ServerName www.web1.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/web1/web1/wsgi.py


    <Directory /var/www/web1/web1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.web1.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin me@web2.com
    ServerName www.web2.com
    ServerAlias web2.com *.web2.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/web2/web2/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/web2/web2>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.web2.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

**With this configuration, I can run httpd and visit web1.com successfully. However, when I tried to visit web2.com, a "Internal Server Error" appear. 
So I went to check the log, it seemed that the "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" set by myblog(web2) project is overrided by that of web1? Does any body know how to solve this problem? Thank you!**

```
<code>
[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97] mod_wsgi (pid=27246): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myblog/myblog/wsgi.py'.

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]     self.load_middleware()

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]     for middleware_path in 
settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]     self._setup()

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

[Thu Jan 10 00:22:38 2013] [error] [client 220.181.108.97] ImportError: Could not import settings 'myblog.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myblog.settings
~                                               
</code>
```

Comment: in your wsgi.py file add the project path to the sys.path

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion would be to create 2 virtual hosts in your apache configuration

```
www.web1.com on 80
```

and

```
www.web2.com on 81
```

Comment: I tried to. With this configuration, when I visited www.web2.com, the index of www.web1.com appeared.